# Diffraction figure in Sentinel 1

Tags: sentinel-1, radar

I observed what I inteprete as a diffraction figure in Sentinel 1 data, and I have no idea what this is.

You can se it if you go to 50.27252991423117, 38.04210455975978, the date of 2022-01-06, and the band VV.

Any idea of what this stat can be?

**Optionnal data:**
Normally this link shoudl bring you directly to what I mention: https://apps.sentinel-hub.com/eo-browser/?zoom=15&lat=50.27087&lng=38.03514&themeId=DEFAULT-THEME&visualizationUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fservices.sentinel-hub.com%2Fogc%2Fwms%2Ff2068f4f-3c75-42cf-84a1-42948340a846&datasetId=S1_AWS_IW_VVVH&fromTime=2022-01-06T00%3A00%3A00.000Z&toTime=2022-01-06T23%3A59%3A59.999Z&layerId=IW-DV-VV-LINEAR-GAMMA0

The image looks like this:

[image: Sentinel 1 suspected diffraction figure]

At this precise location, according to Google Maps recent picture, there is a house:

[image: True color of the location]

Some important element also: This is one of the location and the periode when the Russian army agregated troops here to invade Ukraine.
Troops where stationned very close to this location, as you can see here:

[image: Proximity of the phenomenon with Russian troops]

**My ideas so far:**

I thought of a sort of military radar interfering with S1.

But the figure are very different than the one presented [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427194/artefacts-in-sentinel-1-imagery) and [here](https://medium.com/@HarelDan/x-marks-the-spot-579cdb1f534b)

Another idea I had, would be a diffraction due to interferences with a sort of Corrugated galvanised iron type of roof (it exist different form and inclinations of it, and they could have a size compatible with length wave of S1).